# How exactly does Azure provides scaling?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud

this is a novice question regarding Azure and general cloud technology.

I am trying to understand how exactly the Azure platform will scale my application and do I need to do anything for it to perform well.

I have an application (C#) that process incoming data and is composed of many classes. Each time a relevant calculation is needed, a new class is instantiated and sits in memory until it finishes its work, then it stays there and listens for new calculation requests via events (until explicitly being disposed of). Of course, this consumes resources. The application might have tenth and hundred of thousands of those instances listening and answering calculation requests.

Question is, will the cloud just grow my environment resources as new instance are loaded, until when?
Will there be a moment where I can't start new instances, or current instances calculations is overloading the system? I don't care about it from the budget side, only from the operational one:
Will the cloud be capable of seamlessly manage it in my behalf or do I need to do anything else in my code?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You will have to redesign your system for the cloud.

In your case I would have done it as follows:

- A set of web roles to receive calculation requests via a web service
- The web role would write the calculation request to a queue
- Then a set of worker roles to poll the queue and do the calculations

In your configuration you can set the number of worker roles to 1 or 100. A minute (or atleast a very short time) after you change the config you have the number of machines requested.

You can also do things like increasing the number of worker roles if the queue grows too long.

Comment: But what if I need 10,000 worker roles? And can I dynamically add roles? Also, the instance might just sit there and listens, can't a few instances run in the same role?

Comment: You can add machines dynamically, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232759.aspx

Comment: 10000 workers roles is OK, just change the config, it will however cost your over 1000 USD per hour. http://blog.toddysm.com/2010/01/windows-azure-role-instance-limits-explained.html

Comment: isn't there a limit of 20 CPU's per role or something like that?

Comment: 20-core limit is the default. You just have to contact Microsoft and request a quota increase (and probably a credit application, if you're going to 1000+ cores). Having said that... I don't find this discussion of 10,000 cores really meaningful.

Comment: In practice new cores come up about 1-2 per minute in my experience, so if you do a massive scale up, it could be quite some time before you have all resources.

Answer (score 4):

This is an excellent question and often a big misconception about Azure.

Azure allows for an ability to adjust amount of compute resources allocated via an REST-API call, but does not automatically adjust your resources for you.  What you're talking about, sounds like the dynamic or automatic scalability.  It needs to be implemented by yourself (there are dozens of examples out there) or you can utilize a third-party service [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com) that can handle most of the scaling scenarios for you.

In order to implement dynamic scaling, you may or may not need to think about it upfront.  I mean you definitely should think about it, but you may not need to do much about it, depending on your requirements and your ability to work with 3rd party vendors.

The hard part about dynamic scalability is not the actual scaling part, but knowing when to scale up and when to scale down.

First of all, Azure will kill all the calls to public load-balanced endpoints if the calls are not done within 1 minute.  Thus, if your calculations take a longer time, you want to plan for asynchronous calculations and utilize queues.  This way allows you to scale up or down based upon queue size.

If your calculations are done quickly and your calls are over rather quickly and incoming clients requesting calculations are not asynchronous, you likely want to track average utilization for previous X amount of time and scale up or down based upon that. In your case, I wouldn't go with this approach, as it sounds too restrictive and non-flexible enough.

Either way, [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com) will work with either pattern or both together.

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide some background: you create model of your service where you specify roles and number of instances of each role. Azure deploys this for you. You can always change this configuration but Azure won't do this for you.
As I know Azure team is thinking on autogrow feature but it is pretty complex to implement right, and all thirdparty solutions that i saw did not do this correctly (not enough data, bad behaviour for spikes).
also starting new instance is not instant operations. so you need to plan ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you are designing to work on Azure or not you are best to work with queues to isolate specific pieces of functionality.

In [Shiraz Bhaiji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938234/how-exactly-does-azure-provides-scaling/4938343#4938343) answer your have two worker processes in Azure, a web worker hosting the web service which adds messages to a queue and a background worker to do calculations.

Then you can increase the number of instances of additional workers or you can increase the size of the instance giving you more resources (CPU, Ram, Network) to handle more web service calls/queue messages per second in the case of the each worker.

In the case of reaching the maximum queue performance you can create multiple queues.

Unless you [automate](http://blogs.southworks.net/mwoloski/2010/10/29/fabrikamshipping-the-provisioning-machinery-built-with-windows-azure/) this scaling you have to explicitly monitor and adjust how you want your application to perform through human interaction.

Comment: Something I read and don't understand about moving messages from roles, is the queue part. By what I understand, the worker needs to check the queue all the time to see if there are any new messages. This seems like allot of work, compared to the event driven nature of desktop apps, isn't it? Isn't there a more efficient way of doing so?

Comment: No there is not. That is because the queues, as the other storage flavors, are accessed through a HTTP RESTful API, so there is no way for the server to notify to the roles that a new message has arrived. I feel like you, I was used to the event driven approach, and this thing of keep a infinite loop or a timer looks just silly, but it has its reasons.

Comment: How about using WCF and some kind of broadcast message protocol. Wouldn't that be more efficient?

Comment: Even better, can't I just use the web role also as the worker, and just add more of them?

Comment: If you're looking to provide synchronous results, then yes, this could be a good approach.  Azure will load balance each request across your web roles (no "sticky sessions") and you can just add more when you need them.  Adding items to queues is really good for getting something else to start work, but there are difficulties indicating when that work is complete and what the result is (this is not mentioned in most of the literature).

Answer (score 1):

> The application might have tenth and
>   hundred of thousands of those
>   instances listening and answering
>   calculation requests.

I don't really understand this part. What if you make those classes stateless (and of course thread safe) so you just need to load one of each?

Can you application scale up gently?

Comment: It can't be stateless since some calculations are being made on more then one message. About scaling up gently - this is exactly what I try to understand...

Comment: "Scale up" is the ability to use all your machine resources and avoid idle times (multithreading, low contention times, etc..), so if you use a bigger machine, your application can handle more requests. In the other hand, "scale out" is the ability of your app to work in parallel with more instances of itself. First you should ensure you can "scale up" gently, otherwise it's gonna be a waste of money to try to scale out.